# Refresh datatables plugin content after modifying a cell with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

Im using [Datatables jQuery plugin.](http://www.datatables.net)
When I modify a cell with jQuery, lets say, with something like this:

```
$(this).html('Error!');
```

Then the datatable seems not to be updated as the filtering function doesn't work well for that row with that modified cell.

Is there a way to make datatables aware of this change in order to be able to still using the filtering?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update datatbles by using `fnUpdate` method. Here is [example of usage from docs](http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/editable.html)